# Multiplayer Testing with Steam Accounts

Tags: multiplayer, online, steam

I'm build a multiplayer first person shooter, that supports 32 players.

What is the best way to test large quantities of players?

I'll need 32 steam accounts, with 32 machines to run on. Less, if I can switch to virtual machines.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking here. Testing is a wide field. What exactly is the problem you want to solve? Finding testers? Organizing tests? Test scheduling? Test methodology? Evaluation of test results? Or do you have some steam-specific problem? What exactly is it?

Comment: How to get 32 concurrent instances of the game running and connected. (User input can be faked with scripts)

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make that clear. Especially considering that the answer you accepted is not addressing automation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to hire and pay for actual testers, like how most AAA companies do it, or release the game in early access, like how most indie game developers do it. Choosing the right option depends on your budget and the current state of the game.